# the more combat sports there are, the less likely warfare is?

Tags: usage

If I change the shortened 'the more combative sports, the less likely warfare' into the full sentence, is it 'the more combat sports ***there are***, the less likely warfare ***is***'?

> Anthropologist Richard Sipes (1973), in a classic study of the
> relationship between sport and violence, tests this notion. Focusing
> on what he calls “combative sports,” those sports including actual
> body contact between opponents or simulated warfare, he hypothesizes
> that if sport is an alternative to violence, then in any given society
> one would expect to find an inverse correlation between the popularity
> of combative sports and the frequency and intensity of warfare. In
> other words, ***the more combative sports*** (e.g., football, hockey,
> boxing, wrestling) ***the less likely warfare***. Using the Human
> Relations Area Files and a sample of 20 societies, Sipes (1973) tests
> the hypothesis and discovers a significant relationship between
> combative sports and violence, but a direct one, not the inverse
> correlation of his hypothesis. According to Sipes’ analysis, the more
> pervasive and popular combative sports are in a society, the more
> likely that society is to engage in war.

[The Anthropology of Sport: An Introduction](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=aGeLoS1pWA4C&pg=PA242&lpg=PA242&dq=combative%20sports%20are%20not%20alternatives%20to%20war%20but%20rather%20are%20reflections%20of%20the%20same%20aggressive%20impulses%20in%20human%20society.&source=bl&ots=D8Hy032pKJ&sig=ACfU3U1zUFhgbhBbGrZ6ypiNArN0hBlTiQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjX67m83oP0AhWBF4gKHZfYDqoQ6AF6BQiOAhAD#v=onepage&q=combative%20sports%20are%20not%20alternatives%20to%20war%20but%20rather%20are%20reflections%20of%20the%20same%20aggressive%20impulses%20in%20human%20society.&f=false)

Comment: "Sport as an ***alternative*** to War" sounds like a daft hypothesis to me. Why wouldn't we expect the *opposite* - that societies given to warfare ("international combat") are *also* likely to both produce and encourage combat / competitiveness at the personal or team level (in sport)? But that's irrelevant to the syntactic issue here. I think this conjunction of ***more combative*** (adjectivally modifying ***sports***) and ***less likely*** (adverbially modifying an implicit verb element such as *[the less likely warfare] **is** [to exist]* is klunky (it's not comparing like with like).

Answer (score 1):

I find the original quotation defective: for me the *less likely* (as opposed to *less* breaks the parallellism, and I need a verb in the second half, eg *The more combative sports, the less likely is warfare*.

Your emendation is fine, though I would expect an inversion *is warfare.*